# Using putpixel() doesn't write pixel values to image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am using `putpixel` on an image (`srcImage`)  which is w = 134 and h = 454.

The code here gets the r,g,b value of a part of the font which is 0,255,0 (which I found through debugging, using print option).

```
image = letters['H']  
r,g,b = image.getpixel((1,1)) #Note r g b values are 0, 255,0
srcImage.putpixel((10,15),(r,g,b))   
srcImage.save('lolmini2.jpg')
```

This code does not throw any error. However, when I check the saved image I cannot spot the pure green pixel.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `putpixel()` and `getpixel()` you should use indexing instead. For `getpixel()` you can use `pixesl[1, 1]` and for putpixel you can use `pixels[1, 1] = (r, g, b)`. It should work the same but it's much faster. `pixels` here is `image.load()`

However, I don't see why it wouldn't work. It should work without a problem. Perhaps the jpeg compression is killing you here. Have you tried saving it as a png/gif file instead? Or setting more than 1 pixel.

Comment: Agreed. The jpeg compression would almost certainly wash out the pixel. PNG is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old post but, for beginners who'd want to stick to `putpixels()` for a while, here's the solution:

initialize the image variable as:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.new('RGB', [200,200], 0x000000)
```

Make sure to initialize it as 'RGB' if you want to manipulate RGB values.

Sometimes people initialize images as:

```
img = Image.new('I', [200, 200], 0x000000)
```

and then try to work with `RGB` values, which **doesn't work**.